# Vesta dwarf planet status

Tags: astronomy, planets, solar-system, definition, asteroids

Now that we have close-up photos of Vesta, which the IAU had previously said was a candidate dwarf planet, when is the IAU going to decide the issue? Personally, Vesta doesn't look round enough to me.

Comment: Isn't it up for a vote at the next IAU meeting? August 20, 2012 in Beijing or something like that?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this question can really be answered in any factual way.  There's a [general definition of "dwarf planet"](http://jtgnew.sjrdesign.net/solsys_dwarfs.html) but the IAU is not known for its rapid turn-arounds.  There is also a mathematical way to figure out when mass is sufficient to spherize a body under self-gravity, but exact parameters of the body itself result in ambiguity in many cases ... so it's Opinion A vs Opinion B.